# Azure DevOps Pipeline failing on Build step due to "missing" package. How do I resolve this issue?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-devops

I am currently trying to set up continuous deployment using an Azure DevOps Pipeline for my ASP MVC web app.  Every check-in triggers this pipeline.  Every time the pipeline runs, it is failing on the build step.  The error it displays is:

```
    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.
D:\a\1\s\FantasyLeague\FantasyLeague.csproj(345,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Build FAILED.

D:\a\1\s\FantasyLeague\FantasyLeague.csproj(345,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.47
```

Right before this step in the pipeline there is a restore step that should restore any missing NuGet packages, so I am not sure what could be happening and I am new to Azure.  Any help to get me over this hurdle would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Maybe your path is wrong in the build-pipeline?

Comment: Hi Did you try out below solution? How did it go with this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can try enabling `Restore NuGet Packages` option of your build task.

If you are using Classic UI pipeline. This option resides in `Advanced` setting of your build task.

[image]

For yaml pipeline, you can set the `restoreNugetPackages: true`

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**\*.sln' 
    restoreNugetPackages: true
```

Hope above helps!